# Javascript error detecting item in array

Tags: javascript

I am working on a minesweeper game in javascript. The mechanism that is causing me trouble is the for loop inside the Mine object that sets the isBomb variable to true or false.

```
var board = [];
var bombs = [];
var mines;

function findNeighbors(x,y) {
    return 'work in progress'
}

function setup() {
    // create bombs
    for (var i = 0; i < 45; i++) {
        var position = [floor(random(0,15)),floor(random(0,15))];
        if (!bombs.includes(position)) {
            bombs[i] = position;
        }
    }
    // create board
    for (var y = 0; y < 15; y++) {
        board[y] = new Array();
        for (var x = 0; x < 15; x++) {
            board[y][x] = new Mine(y,x);
        }
    }
}

console.log(board);
console.log(bombs);

function Mine(x,y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.neighbors = findNeighbors(this.x,this.y);
    for (var iter = 0; iter < 45; iter++) {
        if (bombs[iter] == [this.x,this.y]) {
            this.isBomb = true;
        }
        else {
            this.isBomb = false;
        }
    }
    this.show = function() {
        return 'show'
    }
    this.setValue = function(value) {
        this.value = value;
        return value;
    }
}
```

When I type bombs[44] in the console for example, it returns something like [5,11] yet when I check if bombs[44] = [5,11] it will always return false.  Is there a specific way I have to denote the [5,11] array for it to be recognized?

Comment: Object / Arrays will only equal each other if they are the exact same instance, ie `[this.x,this.y]` is creating a new instance of an array so it isn't going to equal any previously stored array

Comment: Are you using bombs[44] = [5, 11] or bombs[44] == [5, 11]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you cannot compare two arrays in javascript. What you can do is using join() and then compare as strings in single step,

```
bombs[44].join(",") == [5,11].join(",")
```

Or you can compare the contents of the array individually

Comment: If the answer is working for you pls accept the answer for the stack overflow comunity

Comment: Right, If you have to consider those cases, you can do is, use  join(","), so that will be more effective as there will be a commabetween items

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the conditional expression in your for-loop at the top for (var i = 0; i < 45; i++) to for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)

this will make the loop , go over the full array length with less room for error. for loops can be , error prone and tedious.